# form_for error for edit action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, nested-form-for, cocoon-gem

galleries_controller.rb

```
def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_params)
      if @gallery.save
          redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully created'
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

def update
    if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
      redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery updated'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end

def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :description, :image, photos_attributes: [:id, :image, :_destroy])
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>  
        <% if photo.object.new_record? %>
        <%= render partial: 'photo_fields', locals: {f:f} %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>   
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add photo', f, :photos %>
</div>
```

_photo_fields.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.file_field :image, class: "add-image-field" %>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f %>
```

gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? },
                                :allow_destroy => true

  validates :title, :description, presence: true
```

photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery

  has_attached_file :image
```

The problem is, i can create new photos via this form, but when i try editing them i get 
undefined local variable or method `f'.

**edit** 
 solution with locals helped abit , but still, i can't run the code smoothly. i edited my code, so i can see which photos are currently uploaded, and added a check box to delete selected photos. But i get unpermitted params: _destroy error when trying to do that.
also:
when i try to add new photos to existing gallery, i get ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in GalleriesController#update. Everything works fine when creating new gallery with several photos. 
it has something to do with currently uploaded pictures, i created a gallery without photos and i could add them on edit action without problems.

```
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f6b174119d0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141030-3930-zycejb>,
     @original_filename="8e16b83685ab70a561d1facae3a023da.jpg",
     @content_type="image/jpeg",
     @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[image]\"; filename=\"8e16b83685ab70a561d1facae3a023da.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
     "_destroy"=>"0",
     "photos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"8"},
     "1"=>{"id"=>"9"}}},
     "commit"=>"Update gallery",
     "id"=>"21"}
```

since i don't have enouhg reputation to post images directly here, i'm pasting a link of how my edit page currently looks liks : http://s13.postimg.org/3o8uvansn/Screenshot_from_2014_11_01_12_55_17.jpg

quick edit: seems that i fixed update problem. this line

```
<% if photo.object.new_record? %>
```

in _form.html.erb lets me upload new pictures. the problem with unpermitted paramaters when deleting persists.

```
link_to_remove_association
```

only removes new file field for pic uploading, it does not remove already uploaded pic.

Comment: change this and try ` <%= render partial: 'photo_fields', locals: {f: f} %>`

Comment: Correct indentation is important to easily reading and understanding code. This will help yourself, and more importantly: readers like me wanting to understand and help you.

Comment: Instead of adding your own `_destroy` checkbox, did you try using `link_to_remove_assocation`?

Comment: i edited main post, from the img you can see what's the problem.